Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' Android resource linking failed style/zxing_CaptureTheme
Hi there guys hope you are great. I need help with this error I'm getting when trying to run my flutter app.
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/user/Projects/Flutter/flutter_app/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:193: error: resource style/zxing_CaptureTheme (aka com.example.flutterapp:style/zxing_CaptureTheme) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.

I use flutter clean, pub get and doctor. So far can't find a way to fix this error.
Hope anyone can help, I really will be thankful.
Note: build.gradle compileSdkVersion up to 33.

Good night guys,
I hope this answer helps anyone who gets into the same mess I did. I have a dependency package for printing receipts in thermal printers through Bluetooth.
The dependency in question is: blue_thermal_printer: 1.2.3
https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer
This package has resource style/zxing_CaptureTheme declared in the package manifest AndroidManifest.xml. this source is no longer available apparently.
This mess started because I ran Flutter Clean, upgraded a few dependencies, and cleared my gradle cache.
In my case, I had two scenarios to ponder:

The first one was to give up my updates for the moment and restore a previous version of the project, which I did, the pressure of the moment.

The second, is to update all necessary dependencies, ditch the one with the issue and replace it with a new one. I will do this because I need my app to print in iOS and the blue_thermal_printer: 1.2.3 won't do because is Android only.


I hope this can be of any help to anyone.
